# What's the best way to update multiple TextInput in a List with Redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have this code to update some TextInputs displayed with a list (AccordionList) in Redux. But the value makes 2 seconds to refresh after I type some text and leave the field (onBlur).

Example : I type my text, I leave the field, it puts the previous value and then, after 2 seconds, the value is changed with the new one.

I think it's not the best way to do that but I don't know how to make this different.

**Here is the code :**

```
const PieceForm = (props) => {

 //Get from Redux Store for default value of each TextInputs
 const [remarques, setRemarques] = React.useState(getRemarques); 

 //Used to change the text
 const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("");

 ....

 //Used to update my remarques on Store and State when leave the field (onBlur)
 function updateRemarque(review) {

        //Send to the store
        let valueToSend = [{
            text: text,
            review: review,
            PieceId: piece.id,
            LieuId: lieuId
        }]

        const action = {type: "UPDATE_REMARQUE", value: valueToSend}

        props.dispatch(action)

        //Update remarques state to have the value on the TextInput
        let newRemarque = [...remarques]
        newRemarque[review.id] = text

        setRemarques(
            newRemarque
        )


    }

 //Render my fields from AccordionList
 const _body = (item) => {
  return (

            <View style={[{padding: 30}]}>

            //My TextInput with default value from remarques state
            <TextInput
                    placeholder='Remarques complémentaires'
                    style={[GLOBAL.selectLegend]}
                    multiline={true}
                    onChangeText={onChangeText}
                    onBlur={() => updateRemarque(item)}
                    value={remarques[item.id]}
                />
            </View>

        );
    }

 return(

  //Render The content (Like a FlatList)
   <AccordionList
                    nestedScrollEnabled
                    data={reviews}
                    keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
                    body={_body}
                    ListFooterComponent={_footer}
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        paddingBottom: 15,
                        paddingTop: 30
                    }}
    />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use onBlur thats what is slowing you down.  Choose to either use state or redux for the textfields and change that with onChange callback.  If you want it in redux, just fire the action on text change and make value equal to the redux value.